# Не могу узнать общее количество элементов в массиве Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex

Файл который берет данные из store из Vuex.
Когда я добавляю в корзину то считается только элементы которые отличаются, но при добавлении одинаковых просто не увеличиваются больше одного

```
<template>
  <div class="v-catalog">
    <router-link :to="{name: 'cart', params: {cart_data: CART}}">
      <div class="v-catalog__link_to_cart">Cart: {{CART.length}}</div>
    </router-link>

    <h1>catalog</h1>
    <div class="v-catalog__list">
      <v-catalog-item
        v-for="product in PRODUCTS"
        :key="product.article"
        :product_data="product"
        @addToCart="addToCart"
      ></v-catalog-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

в Store простой массив
cart: []

Answer (score 0):

Что значит - "только те, которые отличаются"? Вы берете данные напрямую из vuex? Через геттер или напрямую ссылаетесь? А при добавлении элемента в корзину - вы добавляете его напрямую в vuex или через мутации? Лучше приведите код ваших методов, тогда будет проще ответить на ваш вопрос, пока предварительно предположу что дело в реактивности - вы добавляете в массив новый элемент, vue его считает в общем количестве - то есть vue видит что массив измненился. Но при изменении элемента массива, который уже был там - vue не отслеживает изменения и соответственно не отрисовывает изменение количества. В метод после изменения колличества существующего элемента массива можно добавить: arr.splice(arr.length) , где arr - ваш массив корзины. Для понимания этой темы советую почитать [документацию](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: CART.length высчитавыет общее количество но оно как говорилось не высчитывает похожие элементы

Comment: Вы предоставили только template, предоставьте, пожалуйста, используемые методы и данные, чтобы можно было помочь как-то более существенно, пока же не понятно что вы имеете в виду чтобы помочь. Какая у вас механика добавления в корзину? Вы всегда пушите в массив CART новый элемент в не зависимости от того, есть там уже такой элемент или нет? В таких случаях обычно проверяется имеется ли уже такой объект в массиве и если есть - меняется значение количества товара, а если нет - в массив пушится новый объект.

Comment: SET_CART: (state, product) => {
    if (state.cart.length) {
      let isProductExist = false;
      state.cart.map(function(item) {
        if (item.article === product.article) {
          isProductExist = true;

          item.quantity++;
        }
      });
      if (!isProductExist) {
        state.cart.push(product);
      }
    } else {
      state.cart.push(product);
    }
  },
мутация выглядит так

Comment: Примерно представил. У вас vue отрисовывает изменения если при state.cart.push(product) и не отрисовывает если продукт уже имеется в массиве и вы только увеличиваете количество (item.quantity++), верно? 

Если так, то попробуйте после item.quantity++; дописать  state.cart.splice(state.cart.length). Должно получиться так:

isProductExist = true;
item.quantity++;
state.cart.splice(state.cart.length);

Comment: Либо можете просто дописать эту строку в конце мутации после всех проверок условий, вне if ... else. По факту этот код никак не изменит массив, но vue отметит что с массивом произошли изменения в глобальном плане, а не только с конкретным элементом по индексу - и отрисует изменения, отпишитесь как попробуете

Comment: Получается что он также считывает количество запушенных элементов из массива по индексу

Comment: Vue делает все согласно документации:    
*Vue не может отследить следующие изменения в массиве:    
- Прямую установку элемента по индексу: `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`    
- Явное изменение длины массива: `vm.items.length = newLength`    
Решить первую проблему можно двумя способами, оба дадут эффект аналогичный `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`, плюс запустят реактивные обновления состояния приложения    
- Использовать `Vue.set`    
- Использовать `Array.prototype.splice`*

Comment: [Подробнее про реактивность для массивов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2)  В итоге у вас получилось динамически отображать добавление в корзину?

Comment: Я только начинаю свой путь во фронт энд, очень хотелось бы чтобы вы дали мне свой телеграм^__^ Плииз

Comment: Можете найти меня в телеграмме по юзернейму *@Iaicox*